# how can i make a value from variable be a function name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

i created an exercise program that create a dynamic menu from json. and then, everytime i clicked that dynamic menu, a tab will appear having a tab name depending on what is the name of the tab you are clicking.

what i want now, that i'm still figuring out, is that everytime i clicked the menu, it will call a function which have the same name of the menu i clicked., but i just dont know how to do it. my js functions is a separate file. here's the code:

```
    ....
    $('.menu').click(function () {
       dyna_tabs.add('Tab' + $(this).attr("rel"),  //this is for the <a href= "-">
       $(this).attr("rel"),                         //this if for the title
       $(this).html());                             // for the tab_content
       fname = $(this).html();                     // this is my variable name which i plan to use as function name
       alert('this would be my function name ' + fname);
       fname();
    }); 
    ....
```

you can find the rest of the dynamic tab code [here](http://blog.favrik.com/2009/08/11/dynamically-adding-jquery-tabs-round2/). i just did some edit that would create a menu then tab from the menu.

so... i type `fname();` where fname holds the value of the supposedly my function name. but everytime i run my program, an error message shows "fname is not a function". can anybody here knows how to do this right? please....

and one more thing, is anybody knows how put some html codes inside my dynamic tab.? or a .html page inside it? thank you for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another function that will call the necessary function. Like:

```
loader(fname);

function loader(s) {
  switch(s) {
    case 'xy': xy(); break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Your other option might be to store your functions in an object:

```
var myFunctions={
  'xy' : function () {
    //do something here
  },
  ...
};
```

and then you can call them easily like:

```
myFunctions[fname];
```

These are not complete solutions, just some guidelines that you could follow. The advantage over eval is that with these solutions it cannot happen that a function you have not intended to run could run. Only the predefined ones can be called.

Comment: @ bazmegakapa, thank you on this. this works. i just have to learn more on how to do it with more arguments (if its possible). by the way, is it ok to put a function inside a switch? thanks a lot bazmegakapa

Comment: function inside a switch, SOLVED. now is how to add my jqgrid from a html file inside my dynamic tab, in another html file...hmmm..

Comment: you are always free to ask your next question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will apologize for this in advance.

```
eval(fname + '()');
```

should work

According to this question ([How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/javascript-function-name-as-a-string)) there are some better alternatives.

Comment: But only use this if you are aware of the dangers.

Comment: Yeah, let's call the menu item "close" ;)