# How can I call a function whose name is an attribute value in a template?

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has a lot of attributes.

One of them is a  callback, which contains the of the callback function what I want to call.

```
<form  id="placeOrder" method="post" class="ajax" popupclass="order-created"  callback="orderCreated" action="url" >
```

and the JS part is:

```
    function popupHandler(sender){
    var popupclass  = $(sender).attr('popupclass');
    var callback    = $(sender).attr('callback');

    if ((typeof popupclass== "undefined") )
    {
        $("#pageContent").clickPopup('saved');
    }
    else
    {
        if ((typeof callback!= "undefined") )
        {
            //TODO: call the function , function name is in callback attr

        }
        $("#pageContent").clickPopup(popupclass);
    }
    } 

function orderCreated(){
    $('#basketquantity').html('0');
    $('#placeOrderButton').disableButton();
}
```

I have checked this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417621/how-can-i-make-a-value-from-variable-be-a-function-name) , but the name of the functions are predefined there , so that is not suitable for me.

Comment: hey, I've no other way to communicate to you. go undelete your recent answer. it's the only right answer so far. just check for these .. and . in the code, Not a big deal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string in the attr represents the name of a globally scoped function, you can call it via `window[callback]();`

Although I wouldn't use custom attrs like you plan to, if I were to do what you propose it would look like:

```
var orderCreated = function()
    {
      $( '#basketquantity' ).html( '0' );
      $( '#placeOrderButton' ).disableButton();
    },
    popupHandler = function( sender )
    {
      var $sender = $( sender ),
          $pageContent = $( '#pageContent' ),
          popupclass = $sender.attr( 'popupclass' ),
          callback = $sender.attr( 'callback' );

      if( typeof popupclass === 'undefined' )
      {
        $pageContent.clickPopup( 'saved' );
      }
      else
      {
        if( typeof callback !== 'undefined' && typeof window[callback] === 'function' )
        {
          window[callback]();
        }

        $pageContent.clickPopup( popupclass );
      }
    };
```

Comment: the problem is that , what happen, if I call the different callback?
Can I use this one? window[callback]();

Comment: Ok, I will check it.  Can you tell me , why do you use a  var before the function name? It seems like a Jquery plugin .

Comment: function statements, such as `function foo(){}` are modified by JavaScript's hoisting mechanism at run time such as to break them into a var declaration (`var foo;` -which is moved to the top of the scope), and an assignment of the function definition (`foo = function(){};`) which is moved to just below the var declarations. By avoiding function statements and explicitly declaring my vars and assigning functions into them, I avoid the pitfalls which hoisting can cause.

Comment: window.orderCreated=function(){
    $('#basketquantity').html('0');
    $('#placeOrderButton').disableButton();
}

i need to define the orderCreated function like this , then it works with your code :)

Comment: Yes, this all depends on the callback function being scoped to the window.  I have no way of knowing where your posted code is run to know what scope it would have ended up in.  Glad you resolved it.

Comment: Otherwise eval(callback); makes a same thing I think. Thank you your help again, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the function is global it is within the `window`.  So you can call it like this:

```
window[callBackAsString]();
```